# How do I match successive nodes with Nokogiri?

Tags: html, css, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I need to use Nokogiri and CSS or XPath selectors to match text from the following HTML.  It should match starting on a `<div>` tag where `class="propsBar"` and end the match at the closing side of a `<div>` tag where the `class="oddsInfoBottom"`.  This should be done to identify all matches to this pattern:

```
<div class="timeBar"></div>
<div class="propsBar"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoTop"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoBottom"></div>
<!--
 BUY POINTS 
-->
<input id="events[X2036-907-Yes-No-081414]" type="hidden" value="X2036-907-Yes-No-081414^No^Yes^Nationals (S Strasburg) @ Met…l there be a score in the 1st Inning?^8/14/2014^7:10 PM^2036" name="events[X2036-907-Yes-No-081414]"></input>
<div class="timeBar"></div>
<div class="propsBar"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoTop"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoBottom"></div>
<!--
 BUY POINTS 
-->
<input id="events[X2036-915-Yes-No-081414]" type="hidden" value="X2036-915-Yes-No-081414^No^Yes^Astros (S Feldman) @ Red Sox …l there be a score in the 1st Inning?^8/14/2014^7:10 PM^2036" name="events[X2036-915-Yes-No-081414]"></input>
<div class="timeBar"></div>
<div class="propsBar"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoTop"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoBottom"></div>
<!--
 BUY POINTS 
-->
<input id="events[X2036-917-Yes-No-081414]" type="hidden" value="X2036-917-Yes-No-081414^No^Yes^Rays (J Odorizzi) @ Rangers (…l there be a score in the 1st Inning?^8/14/2014^8:05 PM^2036" name="events[X2036-917-Yes-No-081414]"></input>
<div class="timeBar"></div>
```

The above HTML should return three matches.

The only way I have been able to do this so far is:

```
one = html.xpath("//div[@class='propsBar']")
two = html.xpath("//div[@class='oddsInfoTop']")
three = html.xpath("//div[@class='oddsInfoBottom']")

one.zip(two, three).flatten.each_slice(3).map(&:join)
```

This has the downside of returning just the text, no longer as a Nokogiri element. Furthermore, I think it's dangerous to parse this way, if the page has differing numbers of elements that match `one, two, three` it will break.

Comment: What XPath queries have you tried?

Comment: "Demanding"? It's an expectation that you'll provide a sample of what has been tried because it shows you're not just fishing for code someone else writes for you.  It is also easier for us to fix your code than it is for us to write code and you to shoehorn it into whatever you've written. It also helps us head off problems if you're going down the wrong path. Stack Overflow isn't only a "fix my problem" site, it's also a "help me learn and grow through best practices" site. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254575/128421 is a good Meta answer, especially item #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write it something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div class="timeBar"></div>
<div class="propsBar"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoTop"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoBottom"></div>
<!--
 BUY POINTS
-->
<div class="timeBar"></div>
<div class="propsBar"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoTop"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoBottom"></div>
<!--
 BUY POINTS
-->
<div class="timeBar"></div>
<div class="propsBar"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoTop"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoBottom"></div>
<!--
 BUY POINTS
-->
<div class="timeBar"></div>
EOT

found_nodes = doc.search('div.propsBar').map{ |node|
  nodes = [node]
  loop do
    node = node.next_sibling
    nodes << node
    break if node['class'] == 'oddsInfoBottom'
  end
  nodes
}
```

(Notice that I stripped out the `<input>` tags as those only clutter the input HTML. When you supply input data, remove everything that is noise.)

Running that returns the nodes found as an array of arrays. Each sub-array contains the individual nodes found after sequentially walking the sibling chains:

```
require 'pp'
pp found_nodes
# >> [[#(Element:0x3ff00a4936a0 {
# >>     name = "div",
# >>     attributes = [
# >>       #(Attr:0x3ff00a037c28 { name = "class", value = "propsBar" })]
# >>     }),
# >>   #(Text "\n"),
# >>   #(Element:0x3ff00a49363c {
# >>     name = "div",
# >>     attributes = [
# >>       #(Attr:0x3ff00a03629c { name = "class", value = "oddsInfoTop" })]
# >>     }),
# >>   #(Text "\n"),
# >>   #(Element:0x3ff00a4935b0 {
# >>     name = "div",
# >>     attributes = [
# >>       #(Attr:0x3ff00a4668f8 { name = "class", value = "oddsInfoBottom" })]
# >>     })],
# >>  [#(Element:0x3ff00a49354c {
# >>     name = "div",
# >>     attributes = [
# >>       #(Attr:0x3ff00a45c808 { name = "class", value = "propsBar" })]
# >>     }),
# >>   #(Text "\n"),
# >>   #(Element:0x3ff00a4934e8 {
# >>     name = "div",
# >>     attributes = [
# >>       #(Attr:0x3ff00a45b084 { name = "class", value = "oddsInfoTop" })]
# >>     }),
# >>   #(Text "\n"),
# >>   #(Element:0x3ff00a49345c {
# >>     name = "div",
# >>     attributes = [
# >>       #(Attr:0x3ff00a8710ec { name = "class", value = "oddsInfoBottom" })]
# >>     })],
# >>  [#(Element:0x3ff00a4933f8 {
# >>     name = "div",
# >>     attributes = [
# >>       #(Attr:0x3ff00a4979d0 { name = "class", value = "propsBar" })]
# >>     }),
# >>   #(Text "\n"),
# >>   #(Element:0x3ff00a493394 {
# >>     name = "div",
# >>     attributes = [
# >>       #(Attr:0x3ff00a47e188 { name = "class", value = "oddsInfoTop" })]
# >>     }),
# >>   #(Text "\n"),
# >>   #(Element:0x3ff00a493308 {
# >>     name = "div",
# >>     attributes = [
# >>       #(Attr:0x3ff00a458f00 { name = "class", value = "oddsInfoBottom" })]
# >>     })]]
```

Remember that after parsing, the document is a linked list of nodes. If there is a line-break in the original XML or HTML, there'll be a Text node containing at least a new-line character ("`\n`"). Because it's a list, we can move forward and backwards using [`next_sibling`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-next_sibling) and [`previous_sibling`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-previous_sibling) respectively. That makes it *really* easy to grab little chunks, even if they aren't block tags containing the content you want.

If you want the returned values to resemble the output of a [`search`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search), [`css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css) or [`xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) method, the inner variable `nodes` will need to change from an Array to a [NodeSet](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-c-new):

```
found_nodes = doc.search('div.propsBar').map{ |node|
  nodes = Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet.new(doc, [node])
  loop do
    node = node.next_sibling
    nodes << node
    break if node['class'] == 'oddsInfoBottom'
  end
  nodes
}

require 'pp'
pp found_nodes.map(&:to_html)
```

Running that results in:

```
# >> ["<div class=\"propsBar\"></div>\n<div class=\"oddsInfoTop\"></div>\n<div class=\"oddsInfoBottom\"></div>",
# >>  "<div class=\"propsBar\"></div>\n<div class=\"oddsInfoTop\"></div>\n<div class=\"oddsInfoBottom\"></div>",
# >>  "<div class=\"propsBar\"></div>\n<div class=\"oddsInfoTop\"></div>\n<div class=\"oddsInfoBottom\"></div>"]
```

Finally, notice I used CSS selectors rather than XPath. I prefer them because they are usually more readable and succinct. XPath is more powerful and, because it's made for dissecting XML, can often do all the heavy lifting that we'd have to do in Ruby after a CSS selector only gets us close to what we wanted. Use whichever gets the job done for you, with consideration for what is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: this works.  i'm gonna accept this answer.  i think yours as well as 7stud's works but yours is more concise, and intuitive, to me at least. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use Nokogiri, CSS selectors, or Xpath to match text from the
>   following HTML. It should match starting on a  tag where
>   class="propsBar" and end the match at the closing side of a  tag
>   where the class="oddsInfoBottom"

But they are all the same, e.g.:

```
<div class="propsBar"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoTop"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoBottom"></div>
```

Okay, here goes:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.read("xml3.xml"))

doc.css('div.propsBar').each do |div|
  puts div.to_html
  current_node = div

  while current_node = current_node.next_element
    puts current_node.to_html

    if current_node.has_attribute?'class'
      if current_node['class'].match /\b oddsInfoBottom \b/xm
        puts "-" * 10
        break  #Go get a new starting tag
      end
    end
  end
end

--output:--
<div class="propsBar"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoTop"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoBottom"></div>
----------
<div class="propsBar"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoTop"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoBottom"></div>
----------
<div class="propsBar"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoTop"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoBottom"></div>
----------
```

> But this has the downside of returning just the text, no longer as a
>   Nokogiri element.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.read("xml3.xml"))

groups = []
this_group = []

doc.css('div.propsBar').each do |tag|
  this_group << tag
  current_tag = tag

  while current_tag = current_tag.next_element
    this_group << current_tag

    if current_tag.has_attribute?'class'
      if current_tag['class'].match /\b oddsInfoBottom \b/xm
        groups << this_group
        this_group = []
        break
      end
    end
  end

end


groups.each do |group|
  group.each do |tag|
    puts tag.to_html
  end
  puts '-' * 10
end

--output:--
<div class="propsBar"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoTop"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoBottom"></div>
----------
<div class="propsBar"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoTop"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoBottom"></div>
----------
<div class="propsBar"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoTop"></div>
<div class="oddsInfoBottom"></div>
----------
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `+`:

```
doc.search('.propsBar').each do |props_bar|
  odds_info_top = props_bar.at('+ .oddsInfoTop')
  puts props_bar.text, odds_info_top.text
end
```